# Laravel add to cart issue

Tags: php, laravel

Trying to writer add to cart script in laravel. Created a class called cart, Created a product controller where i get product details with product name, quantity, price using an array additem

```
class Cart
{
    public $items;
    public $totalQuantity;
    public $totalPrice;

    public function __construct($prevCart)
    {
        if ($prevCart != null) {
            $this->items = $prevCart->items;
            $this->totalQuantity = $prevCart->totalQuantity;
            $this->totalPrice = $prevCart->totalPrice;
        } else {
            $this->items = [];
            $this->totalQuantity = 0;
            $this->totalPrice = 0;
        }
    }

    public function additem($id, $product)
    {
        $price = (int)str_replace('$', '', $product->price)
        //item already exists
        if (array_key_exists($id, $this->items)) {
            $productToAdd = $this->items[$id];
            $productToAdd['quantity']++;
        } else {
            $productToAdd = ['quantity' => 1, 'price' => $price, 'date' => $product];
        }

        $this->items[$id] = $productToAdd;
        $this->totalQuantity++;
        $this->totalPrice = $this->totalPrice + $price;
    }
}
```

It shows the following error:

> syntax error, unexpected 'if' (T_IF)

Comment: you are missing a semicolon `$price= (int) str_replace('$','',$product->price)` end of this line

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you are missing a closing ';' in this row:

```
$price= (int) str_replace('$','',$product->price)
```

the 'unexpected' error in php should always remind you to check for it.
hope this helps:)